# After Image Rotation and filling black area

Tags: python, opencv

I cropped and rotated to picture and I want to fill boundary. I made mask with black area. and filled with average pixel of 4 point of cropped image. Here is the filled image :

[image: filled]

Here is the cropped and rotated image :

[image: cropped_rotated]

Here is my code :

```
sumarr = (cropped_image[5][5]).astype(int)+cropped_image[-5][-5].astype(int)+cropped_image[5][-5].astype(int)+cropped_image[-5][5].astype(int)
avg1 = sumarr[0]/4 
avg2 = sumarr[1]/4
avg3 = sumarr[2]/4

target_value = [0, 0, 0]
background_value = [avg1, avg2, avg3] 
mask = np.any(new_image == target_value, axis=-1)
new_image[mask] = background_value
```

How can I remove that black line?

Comment: How did you rotate it?

Comment: Is the image with the light grey background the output or is the image with the dark black background the output?